# Dynamic PIVOT select query on SQL Server transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

My table data in this structure below given.

| Firstname | Lastname | Attribute | Attribute_section | Attribute_index | Attribute_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Timoty | Richard | personal | age | 0 | 20 |
| Timoty | Richard | personal | nickname | 0 | Tim |
| Timoty | Richard | personal | nickname | 1 | Tom |
| Timoty | Richard | personal | gender | 0 | Male |
| Timoty | Richard | type_meal | drink | 0 | Coke |
| Timoty | Richard | type_meal | food | 0 | Pizza |
| Timoty | Richard | type_meal | food | 1 | Burger |
| Timoty | Richard | contact | mobile_number | 0 | +998347987278 |
| Timoty | Richard | contact | mobile_number | 1 | +998347987287 |
| Albert | Gerhard | personal | age | 0 | 50 |
| Albert | Gerhard | personal | gender | 0 | Male |
| Albert | Gerhard | type_meal | drink | 0 | Pepsi |
| Albert | Gerhard | type_meal | food | 0 | Pizza |
| Albert | Gerhard | type_meal | food | 1 | Hamburger |
| Albert | Gerhard | contact | mobile_number | 0 | +913453564654 |
| Albert | Gerhard | profession | job | 0 | Doctor |
| Maria | Branyas | personal | age | 0 | 45 |
| Maria | Branyas | personal | gender | 0 | Female |
| Maria | Branyas | type_meal | food | 0 | Salad |
| Maria | Branyas | type_meal | food | 1 | Burger |
| Maria | Branyas | profession | job | 0 | Teacher |
| Maria | Branyas | addprofession | job | 0 | Tutor |

> i would like to have display in this way. Could help on this how to do select query dynamically?

[image]

Comment: What query have you attempted? Please add this into the question and we can help with the parts you don't understand. NB I believe you could avoid dynamic sql, perhaps start with search for "conditional aggregates".

Comment: I think you need to approach this in two steps. First, perform a `GROUP BY Firstname, Lastname, Attribute, Attribute_section` and use the `STRING_AGG()` function to build comma-separated lists of ordered attribute values. Next, feed that into an outer query that just groups on name and then uses ***conditional aggregation*** to separate the attributes into individual columns using expressions like `MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'type_meal' AND Attribute_section = 'food' THEN value_list END) AS type_meal_food`. If you don't know the attributes ahead of time, you will need to use ***dynamic SQL***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to approach this in two steps. First, perform a `GROUP BY Firstname, Lastname, Attribute, Attribute_section` and use the `STRING_AGG()` function to build comma-separated lists of ordered attribute values. Next, feed that into an outer query that just groups on `Firstname, Lastname` and use ***conditional aggregation*** to separate the attributes into individual columns. A PIVOT can also be used (see addendum at end of post).

*Conditional aggregation* is a technique where you place a `CASE` expression inside an aggregation function like `SUM()` or `MAX()` to limit the data that contributes to that particular select item, for example `MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'type_meal' AND Attribute_section = 'food' THEN value_list END) AS type_meal_food`. The omitted `ELSE` defaults to `NULL` when the condition is not true, which is ignored by the aggregate function.

If you know all of the attributes ahead of time, you can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT
    G.Firstname, G.Lastname,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'personal' AND Attribute_section = 'age' THEN Value_list END) AS personal_age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'personal' AND Attribute_section = 'nickname' THEN Value_list END) AS personal_nickname,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'personal' AND Attribute_section = 'gender' THEN Value_list END) AS personal_gender,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'type_meal' AND Attribute_section = 'drink' THEN Value_list END) AS type_meal_drink,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'type_meal' AND Attribute_section = 'food' THEN Value_list END) AS type_meal_food,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'contact' AND Attribute_section = 'mobile_number' THEN Value_list END) AS contact_mobile_number,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'profession' AND Attribute_section = 'job' THEN Value_list END) AS profession_job,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'addprofession' AND Attribute_section = 'job' THEN Value_list END) AS addprofession_job
FROM (
    SELECT
        D.Firstname, D.Lastname, D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section,
        STRING_AGG(D.Attribute_value, ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY D.Attribute_index)
            AS Value_list
    FROM Data D
    GROUP BY D.Firstname, D.Lastname, D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section
 ) G
GROUP BY G.Firstname, G.Lastname
ORDER BY G.Firstname, G.Lastname
```

Result:

| Firstname | Lastname | personal_age | personal_nickname | personal_gender | type_meal_drink | type_meal_food | contact_mobile_number | profession_job | addprofession_job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | Gerhard | 50 | *null* | Male | Pepsi | Pizza, Hamburger | +913453564654 | Doctor | *null* |
| Maria | Branyas | 45 | *null* | Female | *null* | Salad, Burger | *null* | Teacher | Tutor |
| Timoty | Richard | 20 | Tim, Tom | Male | Coke | Pizza, Burger | +998347987278, +998347987287 | *null* | *null* |

If you don't know the attributes ahead of time, you will need to use ***dynamic SQL*** to build out the list of select items, combine that with the rest of the query, and execute the resulting build-out SQL.

```
DECLARE @NewlineIndentComma VARCHAR(50) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '        ,'
DECLARE @AttributeColumnSql VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG(@NewlineIndentComma + SI.SelectItem, '')
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SI.SelectItem)
    FROM (
        SELECT 'MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = ' + QUOTENAME(D.Attribute, '''')
            + ' AND Attribute_section = ' + QUOTENAME(D.Attribute_section, '''')
            + ' THEN Value_list END)'
            + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(D.Attribute + '_' + D.Attribute_section)
            AS SelectItem
        FROM Data D
        GROUP BY D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section
    ) SI
)

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT
        G.Firstname, G.Lastname' + @AttributeColumnSql + '
    FROM (
        SELECT
            D.Firstname, D.Lastname, D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section,
            STRING_AGG(D.Attribute_value, '', '')
                WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY D.Attribute_index)
                AS Value_list
        FROM Data D
        GROUP BY D.Firstname, D.Lastname, D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section
     ) G
    GROUP BY G.Firstname, G.Lastname
    ORDER BY G.Firstname, G.Lastname
'

PRINT @Sql

EXEC (@Sql)
```

The resulting generated query is similar to the first. The `QUOTENAME()` function is used to safely handle potential attribute names containing spaces or special characters.

Results:

| Firstname | Lastname | addprofession_job | contact_mobile_number | personal_age | personal_gender | personal_nickname | profession_job | type_meal_drink | type_meal_food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | Gerhard | *null* | +913453564654 | 50 | Male | *null* | Doctor | Pepsi | Pizza, Hamburger |
| Maria | Branyas | Tutor | *null* | 45 | Female | *null* | Teacher | *null* | Salad, Burger |
| Timoty | Richard | *null* | +998347987278, +998347987287 | 20 | Male | Tim, Tom | *null* | Coke | Pizza, Burger |

Note that the dynamic SQL produces a different column order. If you require a specific ordering, you will need to add logic to define your desired order (possibly using a separate attribute lookup/mapping table that contains an ordinal value) and replace the `ORDER BY SI.SelectItem` part of the dynamic SQL.

If you prefer to replace missing/null attribute values with blank/empty values, you can wrap the select expressions in an `ISNULL(..., '')` function.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PUDI4s5v) for a working example.

*** Addendum ***

As @GlockByte dempnstrated in their answer, a `PIVOT` approach is also an option - with or without dynamic SQL.

The following SQL uses `PIVOT` combined with `STRING_AGG()` to yield the desired results.

```
SELECT PVT.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        D.Firstname, D.Lastname,
        D.Attribute + '_' + D.Attribute_section AS AttributeName,
        STRING_AGG(D.Attribute_value, ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY D.Attribute_index)
            AS Value_list
    FROM Data D
    GROUP BY D.Firstname, D.Lastname, D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section
) G
PIVOT (
    MAX(Value_list)
    FOR AttributeName IN (
        personal_age, personal_nickname, personal_gender,
        type_meal_drink, type_meal_food,
        contact_mobile_number, profession_job, addprofession_job
    )
) PVT
ORDER BY PVT.Firstname, PVT.Lastname
```

Using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @AttributeNameList VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(AN.AttributeName, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY AN.AttributeName)
    FROM (
        SELECT QUOTENAME(D.Attribute + '_' + D.Attribute_section) AS AttributeName
        FROM Data D
        GROUP BY D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section
    ) AN
)

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT PVT.*
    FROM (
        SELECT
            D.Firstname, D.Lastname,
            D.Attribute + ''_'' + D.Attribute_section AS AttributeName,
            STRING_AGG(D.Attribute_value, '', '')
                WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY D.Attribute_index)
                AS Value_list
        FROM Data D
        GROUP BY D.Firstname, D.Lastname, D.Attribute, D.Attribute_section
    ) G
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Value_list)
        FOR AttributeName IN (' + @AttributeNameList + ')
    ) PVT
    ORDER BY PVT.Firstname, PVT.Lastname
'

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

The results are the same as for the *conditional aggregation* approaches shown above.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2X8B7qNu) for an updated working demo that also includes the PIVOT examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple methods to accomplish this. I mixed a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)'s recursive functionality with a [STUFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to demonstrate this. Nonetheless you would need a dynamic query to accomplish your goals since your [PIVOTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) columns are dynamic:

```
/*
    @c will be our columns used for a dynamic pivot
*/

DECLARE @c AS nvarchar(MAX)

/*
    @q will be our variable to hold our query for execution
*/

DECLARE @q AS nvarchar(MAX)

/*
    We create two tables here. #t is to hold the values you provided while #t2 will be for preperations required before the pivot query
    These preparations are 
        1. Combine the strings of Attribute and Attribute_section with an underscore separator
        2. Combine Attribute_values for individuals with multiple of the same attributes with a comma separator
*/

CREATE TABLE #t(
Firstname nvarchar(30),
Lastname nvarchar(30),
Attribute nvarchar(30),
Attribute_section nvarchar(30),
Attribute_index int,
Attribute_value nvarchar(30)
)
CREATE TABLE #t2(
Firstname nvarchar(30),
Lastname nvarchar(30),
Attribute nvarchar(30),
Attribute_value nvarchar(30)
)
INSERT INTO #t
VALUES
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'personal', 'age',  0,  '20'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'personal', 'nickname', 0,  'Tim'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'personal', 'nickname', 1,  'Tom'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'personal', 'gender',   0,  'Male'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'type_meal',    'drink',    0,  'Coke'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'type_meal',    'food', 0,  'Pizza'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'type_meal',    'food', 1,  'Burger'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'contact',  'mobile_number',    0,  '+998347987278'),
('Timoty',  'Richard',  'contact',  'mobile_number',    1,  '+998347987287'),
('Albert',  'Gerhard',  'personal', 'age',  0,  '50'),
('Albert',  'Gerhard',  'personal', 'gender',   0,  'Male'),
('Albert',  'Gerhard',  'type_meal',    'drink',    0,  'Pepsi'),
('Albert',  'Gerhard',  'type_meal',    'food', 0,  'Pizza'),
('Albert',  'Gerhard',  'type_meal',    'food', 1,  'Hamburger'),
('Albert',  'Gerhard',  'contact',  'mobile_number',    0,  '+913453564654'),
('Albert',  'Gerhard',  'profession',   'job',  0,  'Doctor'),
('Maria',   'Branyas',  'personal', 'age',  0,  '45'),
('Maria',   'Branyas',  'personal', 'gender',   0,  'Female'),
('Maria',   'Branyas',  'type_meal',    'food', 0,  'Salad'),
('Maria',   'Branyas',  'type_meal',    'food', 1,  'Burger'),
('Maria',   'Branyas',  'profession',   'job',  0,  'Teacher'),
('Maria',   'Branyas',  'addprofession',    'job',  0,  'Tutor')
/*
    First we use a CTE to concatenate the attributes based on the Attribute_index 
*/

;WITH CTE as(
    SELECT firstName, Lastname, Attribute, Attribute_section, 0 Attribute_index, CAST(Attribute_value AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS Attribute_value
    FROM #t WHERE Attribute_index = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.firstName, t2.Lastname, t2.Attribute, t2.Attribute_section, t2.Attribute_index, CAST(CONCAT_WS(',',CTE.Attribute_value,t2.Attribute_value) AS nvarchar(MAX))
    FROM #t AS t2 INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Firstname = t2.Firstname AND CTE.Lastname = t2.Lastname AND CTE.Attribute = t2.Attribute AND CTE.Attribute_section = t2.Attribute_section
    WHERE t2.Attribute_index = CTE.Attribute_index+1
) 

/*
    Then we insert those into our second table while concatenating the Attribute and Attribute_section
*/

INSERT INTO #t2 SELECT Firstname, Lastname, CONCAT_WS('_',Attribute,Attribute_section) AS Attribute, Attribute_value FROM CTE 

/*
    We set @c as our columns, concatenated with a comma separator and quoted, for the pivot based on a distinct return of all attributes    
*/

SET @c = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Attribute) 
            FROM #t2 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


/*
    Now we can set @q as a string for our pivot query
*/

SET @q = '
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, ' + @c + ' FROM (
    SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Attribute, Attribute_value FROM #t2 
    ) a
    pivot (
        max(Attribute_value)
        FOR Attribute in (' + @c + ')
    ) b '

/*
    execute the query
*/

execute(@q)
```

Comment: Something is not quite right with the attribute concatenation CTE with more than two values. If I add `('Maria',   'Branyas',  'type_meal',    'food', 2,  'Wings'),
('Maria',   'Branyas',  'type_meal',    'food', 3,  'Fries'),
` to the data, I would expect Maria's food to be "Salad, Burger, Wings, Fries", but actual results are "Salad,Wings". See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dKDm3fQe).

Comment: I don't know why I used a bit value. I changed to an INT and added a where clause so the CTE starts at 0 then is recursive by incrementing on the attribute_index. Give it a go now